# How to update Fail Text in RED in TestRail

Tags: html, testrail

I wanted to update the Particular Text like Passed in Green and Failed in RED in TestRail.

It is a text area where we are entering the comment.. But looks like that Textarea will not render html code.

https://www.gurock.com/testrail/docs/user-guide/getting-started/editor

When I read that they are not supporting color for the text area..

```
You cannot use Markdown or HTML within a code block, which makes them a convenient way to show samples of Markdown or HTML syntax:
```

we can not change the HTML page but the only option is passing HTML code to the content.

Any possibility is there?

Answer (score 0):

TestRail does not yet support HTML in text fields, limiting you to markdown, so you can't really add color out-of-the-box.

What you could do is define a pattern for the words you want to highlight and use UI scripts to dynamically add the styles to the page elements, such as in the script below (which you'd have to adapt to your own use case). Breaking it down what it does is:

1. Find the results text elements using the `.change-column-content` class
2. Iterate over the elements
3. Replace the string `[FAILED]` with a styled `<span>`
4. Keeps looping every 2 seconds to find new elements in case the page changes

You can see how it looks like in TestRail in this [TestRail customized results screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARcgb.png). You can also check the [TestRail UI Scripts documentation](https://support.testrail.com/hc/en-us/articles/7344330242196-UI-scripts-examples) for more examples and usage details.

```
name: Customize results text
description: Adds a highlight to string [FAILED] in results history
author: Diogo Rede
version: 1.0
includes: ^runs/view
excludes: 

js:
$(document).ready(function() {
    var get_info = function () {
        $('.change-column-content').each(function (index) {
            if (this.getAttribute("customized") !== 'true') { 
                this.setAttribute("customized", "true");
                this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replaceAll("[FAILED]", "<span class='custom-text'>[FAILED]</span>");
            }
        });
    }

    get_info();
    setInterval(get_info, 2000);
});

css:
.custom-text {
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Testrail is sever which is hosted organization wide..we are able to use. Can we do this??

Comment: @ChanGan UI Scripts can be used in both cloud and server and they will apply to the instance globally, unless you specifically filter out projects or pages in the code itself.